# How do guards affect match statements?

Tags: rust

I simplified an example that comes up in learn rust by example - Guards: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html

```
    let number: u8 = 4;

    match number {
        i if i == 0 => println!("Zero"),
    }
}
```

The example above results in a compilation error regarding the matches cases not being comprehensive. I don't know why. The article says "Note that the compiler won't take guard conditions into account when checking if all patterns are covered by the match expression." But the below example doesn't result in compilation error:

```
match number {
    i => println!("Zero"),
}
```

The difference is I removed the guard. Why did that affect things if the guard isn't supposed to be taken into account?

Comment: Not sure if it's just me, a non-native English speaker, I found it difficult to understand that sentence. I have to read it several times to figure out it's trying to say `The match arm with guard won't be taken into account, when (the compiler) checking if all patterns have been covered.`

Comment: See also [chapter 6, section 2: Matches are Exhaustive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-02-match.html#matches-are-exhaustive)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The doc you cite doesn't say that the guards are not taken into account, it says that the guard *conditions* are not taken into account. This means that the following will fail to compile even though all possible values for `number` are covered:

```
match number {
    i if i >= 0 { 1 },
    i if i < 0  { 0 },
}
```

or even this:

```
match number {
    i if true => { 0 },
}
```

In other words, the fact that there is a guard on a match arm will cause this arm to be ignored completely when checking if the match is complete.

Comment: In yet other words, the compiler assumes that any match guard can fail, since otherwise you could simply omit them. Which is indeed the case in these two examples – in the first one you could omit the match guard on the second arm.